# Is $\mathbb{C}[x,e^x]$ Noetherian?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, noetherian

I want to know how to show that the ring $\mathbb{C}[x,e^x]$ is Noetherian (I know the answer is yes, it is Noetherian, but I'm unable to prove it!).

My initial thoughts were to construct some isomorphism $\mathbb{C}[x,y]\rightarrow \mathbb{C}[x,e^x]$ such as $f(x,y)\mapsto f(x,e^x)$, and use the fact that $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ is Noetherian by the Hilbert Bases Theorem. Such a mapping is a well-defined surjective ring homomorphism, but I'm struggling to prove injectivity in this case: if $f$ is in the kernel then $f(x,e^x)$ is identically zero, and hypothetically we could substitute in $y=e^x$ to give us that $f(x,y)$ identically zero for $y>0$ - the problem being that this is only true for $y>0$!

Please could someone help me figure this out? (Or let me know if I'm barking up at the wrong tree entirely!) Thanks :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**: Quotients of noetherian rings are noetherian.

Comment: I cannot believe I missed that! So I can just apply the first isomorphism theorem to the map I gave above so that $\mathbb{C}[x,e^x]$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ quotiented by the kernel and therefore Noetherian? That is so simple, thank you!

Comment: Exactly :) You are welcome!

Answer (score 2):

To prove your ring is Noetherian, PrudiiArca provided an answer.

If you want to know how to prove that the kernel of your map is trivial: this is in fact equivalent to proving that $e^X$ is transcendental over $\mathbf{C}[X]$. See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1252424/prove-ex-is-transcendental-over-the-polynomials-with-coefficients-in-mathb) or [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/186752/proof-that-ex-is-a-transcendental-function-of-x) answer.